High availability / load balancing methods for on-premises gateways for SaaS systems (gatway initiated connections)
While I have a specific setup I'm writing this as a general question so someone can bring some related ideas.
I have a SaaS that uses a gateway inside my network to connect to my on-premises systems. That gateway is actually a docker container that initiates the connection against the SaaS so there are no publicly exposed elements on my network.
It works in a way very similar to the data gateways Microsoft uses for their Power Platform.
The thing is that docker container is not as stable as it should and sometimes fails or gets overwhelmed by the requests sent from the SaaS.
While Microsoft's data gateways have a cluster mechanism to provide HA/LB, this product doesn't and I can't wait for the  SaaS manufacturer to develop something.
If the connection was initiated on the SaaS side, I could put a load balancer like HA proxy before the on-premises gateway but, since the connections are initiated on the inside, I fail to see what the best approach could be.
I can implement something on the SaaS that checks if there are gateways available and chooses one for its requests, but that's makes a workaround that messes the workflows on the SaaS, makes them "ugly" and way harder to maintain. I would prefer setting something up on the systems operation side instead, so HA could be transparent to the SaaS.
Any ideas?
Maybe something "simple" for HA such as cold containers? Any best practises for this?
